# Raspberry pi 3 wireless error

Tags: network-programming, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

i just purchased new pi 3. [i installed jessie from here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)

there's no problem at installation, `startx` command works, available network wifi also successfully scanned using `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` command. the problem is when i use "ifup wlan0" it replied with `command not found`. so does `ifdown wlan0`. i also tried several raspbian installer such as wheezy and an older jessie, but same problem occured. anyone has same error or is there any solution? thanks in advance

*edited*

just found out that same error occurred on eth0 module. 
here's my interfaces script
(i have try several mode, but same error occurred from default interfaces script to my pi-2 interfaces script)

```
auto lo
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid "wifi-server-test"

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.137.77
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.137.1
```

it seems the main error is the **ifup** and **ifdown** itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifup` and `ifdown` are in the debian package named `ifupdown`.

```
sudo apt-get install ifupdown
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, any idea how to do "apt-get" while both wlan and eth cant connect to the internet?

Comment: if dhclient is missing too,  sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up; sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1; sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf (and add nameserver 8.8.8.8)